# ComboBox required SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, combobox, sapui5, required

I'm trying to make my comboBox type required, but this didn't work. I can't find nothing about this. Do you know how can I achieve this?

This is the code that I tried:

```
<m:ComboBox id="comboId" required="true" placeholder="{i18n>ComboText}" items="{ path: 'model>/PeopleSet' }" selectionChange="onSelect" visible="false">
     <c:ListItem key="{model>Bed}" text="{model>Name}"/>
</m:ComboBox>
```

Comment: What's the purpose of making it required?

Comment: is because it is in a form, so I need to validate that the person choose an option before submit @Marc

Comment: I think usually you set the required property on the label and not the control. Because the red star is rendered directly in the label. The required property is only for rendering purposes and there is no logic involved if the person really chose an option. This has to be implemented manually.

Comment: Then I should put it on the label? It doesn't actually appear as if the person has chosen any option, because what appears is the placeholder. But when saving, the default one is set @Bagazo

Comment: The documentation of the property `required` states that it is only used for accessibility purposes. https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.m.ComboBox#controlProperties